# KeyUp in datagridview with EditOnEnter not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have DataGridView which EditMode is on EditOnEnter. in that case the KeyUP method doesn't work? if i want to have KeyUp i should set the EditMode in EditOnKeyStroke or EditOnKeyStrokeOrF2. 
I have set

```
   this.KeyPreview = true;
```

on Form Load but it doesn't work.
how can i fire Key up in EditOnEnter?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    private void  YourDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ---- Check Column Name is == Your Column Name
            ---- set the EditMode in EditOnKeyStroke or EditOnKeyStrokeOrF2
        }
```

I am giving this Example just because You was not Posted your DataGridView Codes.

UPDATE : AS per Your Need those Events can be Use full...

```
        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString ()); 
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dataGridView1_KeyUp" + e.KeyData );
        }

        private void dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown" + e.KeyData);
        }
```

Comment: Well the KeyUp never Fires up when it is in EditonEnter mode. how is it possible to reach to your code then?